# not getting all data in file using fopen

Tags: c, fopen

I'm using the `fopen` with `fread` for this:

```
FILE *fp;

if (fopen_s(&fp, filePath, "rb"))
{
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    //exit(1);
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

char buffer = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
if (!buffer)
{
    printf("Failed to malloc\n");
    //exit(1);
}

int charsTransferred = fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);
printf("charsTransferred = %d, size = %d\n", charsTransferred, strlen(buffer));

fclose(fp);
```

I'm not getting the file data in the new file. Here is a comparison between the original file (right) and the one that was sent over the network (left):
[image: original file on the right, new file on the left.]

Any issues with my fopen calls?

EDIT: I can't do away with the null terminators, because this is a PDF. If i get rid of them the file will corrupt.

Comment: How do you know you are not reading all the data? All you have shown is that what you receive on the other side is not the full file but not how the data you read in became that file is left unknown. Based on the image you show, it looks like the data is not text but binary, and my guess is that you are using string functions but the "string" has an embedded null character.

Answer (score 5):

Be reassured: the way you're doing the read ensures that you're reading all the data.

1. you're using "rb" so even in windows you're covered against CR+LF conversions
2. you're computing the size all right using `ftell` when at the end of the file
3. you rewind the file
4. you allocate properly.

BUT you're not storing the right variable type:

```
char buffer = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
```

should be

```
char *buffer = malloc(size);
```

(that very wrong and you should correct it, but since you successfully print *some* data, that's not the main issue. Next time enable and *read* the warnings. And don't cast the return value of `malloc`, it's error-prone specially in your case)

Now, the displaying using `printf` and `strlen` which confuses you.

Since the file is binary, you meet a `\0` somewhere, and `printf` prints only the start of the file. If you want to print the contents, you have to perform a loop and print each character (using `charsTransferred` as the limit).

That's the same for `strlen` which stops at the first `\0` character.

The value in `charsTransferred` is correct.

To display the data, you could use `fwrite` to `stdout` (redirect the output or this can crash your terminal because of all the junk chars)

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, size, stdout);
```

Or loop and print only if the char is printable (I'd compare ascii codes for instance)

```
int charsTransferred = fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);
int i;
for (i=0;i<charsTransferred;i++)
{
   char b = buffer[i];
   putchar((b >= ' ') && (b < 128) ? b : "-");
   if (i % 80 == 0) putchar('\n'); // optional linefeed every now and then...
}
fflush(stdout);
```

that code prints dashes for characters outside the standard printable ASCII-range, and the real character otherwise.

Comment: In what way can I avoid the `\0`?

Comment: you cannot, but you can loop through your data to replace all non-ascii chars by dashes for instance. I'll edit to show how to print only ASCII chars.

Comment: Tried your change, issue is when you switch up the `\0`, you also corrupt the file. Any other way you can think of?

Comment: use that loop only for display. if you want to write back the file (pointless since it already exists on your disk, use `fwrite`, or `fwrite` to `stdout`.

Comment: What I want to do is send the PDF though a socket in chunks, if I send it normally or how you have shown me the file becomes corrupted.

Comment: maybe you can edit your question to show how you're sending the data through the socket. You may have an issue with the parameters of the send.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's in the `fopen` section because running `fread` does not get me all of the data in the file. Long before we go into sockets the data is already messed up.

Comment: no, your way to read is OK. Try writing back using `fwrite` in another file, and compare files you'll see it's OK. 1) you're using "rb" so even in windows you're covered, 2) you're computing the size all right 3) you rewind, 4) you allocate properly. But you're storing your allocated pointer in a `char` instead of `char *`. Fix that (although, not the reason why you get truncated data)